# Woocommerce order status from Failed to Processing. No email

Tags: email, triggers, woocommerce

In case, when customer entered wrong credit card data in woocommerce checkout, orders status goes to Failed.
Order status, when customer successfully attempted to enter credit card data, from Failed goes to Processing.
In such scenario, woocommerce doesn’t send standard processing order email to customer.
How to trigger Processing order email when orders status goes from Failed to Processing.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing', 'send_transactional_email' , 10, 10 );

function send_transactional_email( $args = array() ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->mailer();  
    do_action( current_filter() . '_notification', $args );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this code, but i got 2 New Order emails (for admins), but no Processing order to customer. Also i've changed 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing' to 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_processing'

Comment: add_action( 'woocommerce_email', 'trigger_those_mandatory_emails' );

function trigger_those_mandatory_emails( $email_class ) {

  
// New order emails
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_processing_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
}